# Book where people are sent to a distant destination and babies are awakened out of sleep when nearby, problems ensue

Tags: story-identification, books, space-colonization

I read this book MANY years ago. A space mission is sent to a destination many light years away. A set of babies and people to tend/raise them are frozen and awakened when near the destination. The babies are raised, and the usual problems of child-rearing arise to the point that the mission cannot continue. Then the adults are told that this was a practice session, the real babies are now ready to be raised after this practice session.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145651/4318?

Comment: Are you ***sure*** it was "a book", not a novella?

Comment: Could have been a novella, it was a long time ago that I read it

Comment: @marjc so it could be Birthdays by Fred Saberhagen detailed in the Kenster's link above?

Comment: Are there other writings with the same or similar theme?